# What handles the event of changing the email you're looking at in outlook?

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I have a custom toolbar that I want to toggle the visibility for based on some criteria about the current email being viewed in the active inspector. I need to check for this each time the user changes which email he/she is looking at. I'm very new to coding add-ins, but I imagine the code would look something like this:

```
Sub EmailBeingViewed_Change(object, args) Handles 'Whatever-the-event-is-called
    Dim OpenEmail As Outlook.MailItem = CType(object, Outlook.MailItem)
    If OpenEmail.Body 'Contains thing I care about' _ 
    Then
        MyToolbar.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use Explorer.SelectionChange event.